# No module named 'setup_environment'

Tags: python, import, module, directory, environment

here is my code I am using jupyter on aws sagemaker

```
# Environment Setup: 
import sys
import os 
sys.path.append('data-science/commons/')

import setup_environment 
import importlib
importlib.reload(setup_environment)

setup_environment.initialize_env()
```

the file in am writing in is in a different folder and setup_environment.py is the commons folder. Yet I receive an error of 'No module named 'setup_environment'

I tried searching for a similar problems and I faced something called

```
PYTHONPATH environment variable yet I don't know how to set it on sagemaker and not locally
```

Comment: Try to add an empty `__init__.py` file in the folder where the imported code lives. That way you make that folder a package.

Comment: @AndreyKachow already done that but I am still facing the same problem